# Hi, I have a small issue when i converted below script to version 4. The indicator got right shifted

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I converted the below code to version 4 without any error. But the problem is that the indicator got shifted to right, that is, the levels that are supposed to show today is coming up only next day.

The supply and demand zones of today is just showing after todays session.

Please help me to fix this.

```
//CD
//Average Daily Range Levels - 10 day
study(title="CD_Average Daily Range Zones", shorttitle="CD_Daily High/Low Zones V01", overlay=true)
//dayHigh=security(tickerid, 'D', high[1]) 
OPEN=security(tickerid, 'D', open) 
//ADR L
dayrange=(high - low)
r1 = security(tickerid, 'D', dayrange[1]) 
r2 = security(tickerid, 'D', dayrange[2]) 
r3 = security(tickerid, 'D', dayrange[3]) 
r4= security(tickerid, 'D', dayrange[4])
r5= security(tickerid, 'D', dayrange[5])
r6 = security(tickerid, 'D', dayrange[6]) 
r7 = security(tickerid, 'D', dayrange[7]) 
r8 = security(tickerid, 'D', dayrange[8]) 
r9= security(tickerid, 'D', dayrange[9])
r10= security(tickerid, 'D', dayrange[10])



adr_10 = (r1+r2+r3+r4+r5+r6+r7+r8+r9+r10) /10
adr_9 = (r1+r2+r3+r4+r5+r6+r7+r8+r9) /9
adr_8 = (r1+r2+r3+r4+r5+r6+r7+r8) /8
adr_7 = (r1+r2+r3+r4+r5+r6+r7) /7
adr_6 = (r1+r2+r3+r4+r5+r6) /6
adr_5 = (r1+r2+r3+r4+r5) /5
adr_4 = (r1+r2+r3+r4) /4
adr_3 = (r1+r2+r3) /3
adr_2= (r1+r2)/2
adr_1 = r1


//plot 
adrhigh10=plot((OPEN+(adr_10/2)) , title="ADR High10",style=circles,color=red,linewidth=2) 
adrlow10=plot((OPEN-(adr_10/2)), title="ADR LOW10",style=circles, color=green,linewidth=2)
//adrhigh9=plot((OPEN+(adr_9/2)) , title="ADR High9",style=circles,color=red,linewidth=2) 
//adrlow9=plot((OPEN-(adr_9/2)), title="ADR LOW9",style=circles, color=green,linewidth=2)
//adrhigh8=plot((OPEN+(adr_8/2)) , title="ADR High8",style=circles,color=red,linewidth=2) 
//adrlow8=plot((OPEN-(adr_8/2)), title="ADR LOW8",style=circles, color=green,linewidth=2)
//adrhigh7=plot((OPEN+(adr_7/2)) , title="ADR High7",style=circles,color=red,linewidth=2) 
//adrlow7=plot((OPEN-(adr_7/2)), title="ADR LOW7",style=circles, color=green,linewidth=2)
//adrhigh6=plot((OPEN+(adr_6/2)) , title="ADR High6",style=circles,color=red,linewidth=2) 
//adrlow6=plot((OPEN-(adr_6/2)), title="ADR LOW6",style=circles, color=green,linewidth=2)
adrhigh5=plot((OPEN+(adr_5/2)) , title="ADR High5",style=circles,color=red,linewidth=2) 
adrlow5=plot((OPEN-(adr_5/2)), title="ADR LOW5",style=circles, color=green,linewidth=2)
//adrhigh4=plot((OPEN+(adr_4/2)) , title="ADR High4",style=circles,color=red,linewidth=2) 
//adrlow4=plot((OPEN-(adr_4/2)), title="ADR LOW4",style=circles, color=green,linewidth=2)
//adrhigh3=plot((OPEN+(adr_3/2)) , title="ADR High3",style=circles,color=red,linewidth=2) 
//adrlow3=plot((OPEN-(adr_3/2)), title="ADR LOW3",style=circles, color=green,linewidth=2)
//adrhigh2=plot((OPEN+(adr_2/2)) , title="ADR High2",style=circles,color=red,linewidth=2) 
//adrlow2=plot((OPEN-(adr_2/2)), title="ADR LOW2",style=circles, color=green,linewidth=2)
//adrhigh1=plot((OPEN+(adr_1/2)) , title="ADR High1",style=circles,color=red,linewidth=2) 
//adrlow1=plot((OPEN-(adr_1/2)), title="ADR LOW1",style=circles, color=green,linewidth=2)



fill(adrlow10,adrlow5,color=lime)
fill(adrhigh10,adrhigh5,color=maroon)
//fill(adrlow2,adrlow9,color=lime)
//fill(adrhigh2,adrhigh9,color=maroon)
//fill(adrlow3,adrlow8,color=lime)
//fill(adrhigh3,adrhigh8,color=maroon)
//fill(adrlow4,adrlow7,color=lime)
//fill(adrhigh4,adrhigh7,color=maroon)
//fill(adrlow6,adrlow2,color=lime)
//fill(adrhigh6,adrhigh2,color=maroon)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from `v3`, the behavior of the `security` function has changed. You can read more about it [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_3.html#default-behaviour-of-security-function-has-changed).

The default value of the `lookahead` parameter was `barmerge.lookahead_off` in `v2`. Now, it is `barmerge.lookahead_on` from `v3` and onwards.

So, if you want the same behavior, add `lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_off` to your `security` functions.

Please read the other changes from the link I provided.

Comment: Thankyou very much.  lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on worked.

Comment: If my answer solved you issue, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stack-overflow) it so that we know this question has a valid answer.